# Networkx, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'all_simple_paths'

Tags: python, networkx

I am a new user of python-networkx, and somehow it shows an error when I try all_shortest_paths function [here](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths)

ps: I have updated networkx to the latest version

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> print nx.__version__
1.7
>>> G = nx.complete_graph(4)
>>> print nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=0, target=3, cutoff=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'all_simple_paths'
```

Thanks!
the package seems to be installed well and  other functions I tried did't have this problem.

```
>>> print  help(nx)


NAME
    networkx

FILE
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/__init__.py

DESCRIPTION
    NetworkX
    ========

        NetworkX (NX) is a Python package for the creation, manipulation, and
        study of the structure, dynamics, and functions of complex networks.

        https://networkx.lanl.gov/

    Using
    -----

        Just write in Python
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure the package was installed properly?

Comment: what does help(nx) show?